# call F# dll in C#

Tags: c#, dll, f#, reference

How can I create F# dll and call it in C#?
Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To create a DLL in F#, you should set the output type to class library in project properties. Use Add Reference dialog as mentioned before to add the reference in your C# project.

Answer (score 2):

There's no real trick; like

http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!307.entry

only the other way around.  One thing to note is that if you don't specify a namespace in the F# code, all your top-level definitions by default end up in a module with the name of the file, so if you have Program.fs then you may reference Program.Whatever from C#.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the latest version, all you should need to do is set the project type to 'F# Library' when you create the project.