# Building F# library to be used in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, f#, mono

Let's say I have the following function.

```
let rec fib n =
    match n with
    | 1 | 2 -> 1
    | n -> fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

How can I compile this code into dll so that it's used from C#?

I use both mono (in Mac OS X) and Visual Studio 2010.

### ADDED

I added the following to make namespace.

```
namespace MyMath.Core
module public Process=
```

And  fsc --target:library facto.fs gives me facto.dll.

The C# code to use this code as follows.

```
using System;
using MyMath.Core;

class TestFSharp {
    public static void Main() {
        int val = MyMath.Core.Process.fib(10);
        Console.WriteLine(val);
    }
}
```

dmcs /r:facto.dll testf.cs gives me tesetf.exe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [call F# dll in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736956/call-f-dll-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, if you put this in the file Program.fs, and compile it into a [library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233171.aspx) (with `--target:library`), then it would appear from C# as

```
Program.fib(5)
```

See also [call F# dll in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736956/call-f-dll-in-c)

However if you plan to expose F# code to C#, you may want to uses namespaces and types.  See the [F# Component Design Guidelines](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp-component-design-guidelines.pdf) for more.